# Syncthing fails to start as ubuntu systemd service

Tags: ubuntu, sync, home-networking, home-server

I recently setup a home server running ubuntu 16.04.  I installed syncthing on it to sync between my desktop, laptop, and phone.

So I want [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) to run as a system service, meaning the service starts when the PC starts, without me having to log in, but I want it to sync the files in my personal user's home directory (/home/ryan/Sync).

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html#using-systemd), but I'm having an issue where the service fails to start upon system boot.  Here is what I see upon logging in and checking the status...

[image]

Then, all I have to do is run `systemctl start syncthing@ryan.service` and it works fine; but I just want it to start without me having to log in and run the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had something to do with my encrypted home directory.  I guess the OS couldn't start a syncthing process under my local user until I logged in an decrypted my home directory.

In the end I just decided to remove the encryption on my home dir by following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption) instructions.

Everything works great now!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the home folder encrypted and use a system service to sync data from an unencrypted part of your file system, you need to move the location of the Syncthing config folder (`home/{myuser}/.config/syncthing` by default) out of the encrypted home directory, by using the `-home="/path/to/config` argument when running Syncthing.

For example;

- Enable the service, `$ sudo systemctl enable syncthing@{myuser}.service`, and take note of the location of `syncthing@.service` (*e.g.* `/lib/systemd/system/syncthing@.service`).
- Modify the service `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/syncthing@.service`, adding `-home="/path/to/.config/syncthing"` to the `ExecStart=` line;

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for %I
  Documentation=man:syncthing(1)
  After=network.target
  Wants=syncthing-inotify@.service

  [Service]
  User=%i
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0 -home="/path/to/.config/syncthing"
  Restart=on-failure
  SuccessExitStatus=3 4
  RestartForceExitStatus=3 4

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Start the service, `$ sudo systemctl start syncthing@{myuser}.service`, and check the config files have been added to the given path.
- Restart and check the service was already up and running once you log in, `$ systemctl status syncthing@{myuser}.service`.

*n.b.* Make sure not to sync the config folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it as a startup program in Ubuntu so it starts at login instead of using systemctl.

Search the HUD for Startup Applications Choose Add

Name it Syncthing

In 16.04 the command will be /usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -home="/home/youruserfolder/.config/syncthing" replacing youruserfolder.

Add a comment.

Save by clicking add.

Log back out and then in and check your status by going to http://127.0.0.1:8384/